# How do you display time zone in Apple photos

Tags: photos, photos.app

I've seen the following screenshot showing the time zone in the info display in the new photos app.

I can see how to see the time zone if I use the adjust time and date, but it doesn't display in the info display box. [image]

Answer (score 1):

it's actually a setting in "date&time" in your system preferences.

Open it and then in the "date&time" section, click on "open language & Region", then "advanced".

Click on "times" section and add/drag "time zone" to the "short time" format.

Comment: Yes thanks. Someone else had told me that. But while it does display it doesn't display the timezone the photo has assigned  to it, only the current timezone assigned to the computer. So looks promising but doesn't deliver, why would you leave like that Apple???????

Comment: @MikeW: Wow, what an incredible bug!

Comment: Incredible but it still remains like that after the latest Sierra MacOS upgrade???

Comment: Still happening in June 2019